# I have view of categories showing one category after other one, I want to show it but each one in tab can You help?

Tags: joomla-3.x

ok I had view like this

```
<?php
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    if (!$config->show_empty_cat && !count($category->events))
    {
        continue ;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="row-fluid jakis <?php echo $clearfixClass; ?>">
        <h3 class="eb-category-title">
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(EventbookingHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($category->id, $Itemid)); ?>" class="eb-category-title-link">
                <?php
                    echo $category->name;
                ?>
            </a>
        </h3>
        <?php
            if($category->description)
            {
            ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $clearfixClass; ?>"><?php echo $category->description;?></div>
            <?php
            }

            if (count($category->events))
            {
                $user = JFactory::getUser();
                $bootstrapHelper = EventbookingHelperBootstrap::getInstance();

                echo EventbookingHelperHtml::loadCommonLayout('common/events_table.php', array('items' => $category->events, 'config' => $config, 'Itemid' => $Itemid, 'nullDate' => JFactory::getDbo()->getNullDate(), 'ssl' => (int) $config->use_https, 'viewLevels' => $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels(), 'categoryId' => $category->id, 'bootstrapHelper' => $bootstrapHelper));
            }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I try to add tab code but it always show all categories in first tab how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for support.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your template is using bootstrap 2, and assuming you want horizontal tab panels, then the following untested rewrite may get you closer to what you are after?

```
<?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$bootstrapHelper = EventbookingHelperBootstrap::getInstance();
?>
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <?php
    $tab_count = 0;
    foreach ($categories as $category){
        if (!$config->show_empty_cat && !count($category->events)){
            continue;
        }

        $tab_count++;
        echo '<li';
        echo $tab_count == 1 ? ' class="active"' : '';
        echo '><a href="#tab' . $tab_count . '" data-toggle="tab">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <?php
    $tab_count = 0;
    foreach ($categories as $category){
        if (!$config->show_empty_cat && !count($category->events)){
            continue;
        }
    
        $tab_count++;
        echo '<div class="tab-pane';
        echo $tab_count == 1 ? ' active' : '';
        echo ' id="tab' . $tab_count . '">';

        echo !empty($category->description) ? '<div>' . $category->description . '</div>' : '';

        echo EventbookingHelperHtml::loadCommonLayout('common/events_table.php', array('items' => $category->events, 'config' => $config, 'Itemid' => $Itemid, 'nullDate' => JFactory::getDbo()->getNullDate(), 'ssl' => (int) $config->use_https, 'viewLevels' => $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels(), 'categoryId' => $category->id, 'bootstrapHelper' => $bootstrapHelper));
    }

    echo '<a href="' . JRoute::_(EventbookingHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($category->id, $Itemid)) . '" class="btn btn-info">' . $category->name . '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Within the `<div class="tab-content">` markup block, are there potentially too many `<div>` tags created / not enough `</div>` tags?